# iTunes Connect asking me SARN

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I requested iAds contract and then iTunes Connect asked me to choose the country : saudi arabia then iTunes Connect asked me for SARN, so what is the SARN ?

[image]

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of what you're seeing?  At first thought I'd think it is "Saudi Arabia(n) [X] Number."  Reference number?  Registration number?  Is this perhaps related to taxes in your country?  But as I said--screenshot would help.

Comment: I update my question with screenshot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer and it is work with me :

SARN for Saudi National Commercial Bank "البنك الاهلي" is = 10

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your updated screenshot, SARN is apparently some kind of banking information.  Click the links it gives you--first try "Lookup your Bank".  If that doesn't work, click "Contact Us".  What they're trying to do is get info on where to send money you make :)  Alternately you could just try typing in your account routing number (RN almost certainly stands for Routing Number in a banking context!).  Simply follow the instructions it gives you; if typing in your Routing Number doesn't work, Apple will be able to give you customer support :)

Comment: I search about the bank routing number but I did not find anything , also I found swift code : NCCOSAJEXXX but I do not know what to do with it !

Comment: Did you click the "Lookup your Bank" and "Contact Us" buttons?

Comment: What happens when you click "Contact Us"?

Comment: gives me options to select , at the end I can send them my problem but there is required field named routing number and I do not know it

Comment: If you do not know your routing number, you need to call your bank when they're open.  The Routing Number is how other people can send you money without the bank giving them your confidential information.  That is the only way for you to complete this process.

Comment: do you mean card number ? is it the same number when they took the 99$ from my account?

Comment: Assuming it is the same in Saudi Arabia as in the US, this is how to find your routing number: https://unebapps01.nebraska.edu/uwide/essfaq.nsf/074c4f0f90d2366386256d710072e9ce/863962993c910f3486256e9a0068e21d